# Is there an alternative approach to using Itô's lemma for computing this stochastic differential?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

We define $$M_t=(B_t+t)^{-(B_t+\frac{1}{2}t)}$$
Where $B$ is a Brownian motion.

I must compute the stochastic differential of $M_t$, i.e. $dM_t$. I figured this should be possible with Itô's lemma, but I got stuck rather quickly.

I started off by setting $F(x,y)=(x+y)^{-(x-\frac{1}{2}y)}$, and then computing all necessary derivatives, i.e. $F_x,F_{xx},F_y,F_{yy},F_{xy},F_{yx}$. However, these derivatives get quite ugly, especially the double derivatives. In fact, they get so ugly that it got me doubting whether this was even the right approach. Is there a more ''elegant'' way to computing the stochastic differential of $M_t$?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does it worry you that the base $B_t + T$  may be negative for some small times? Of course, you do have $B_t+t>0$ for sufficiently large $t$, a.s.

Comment: @JohnDawkins I must say, that did not worry me, no. Why should it? I'm not sure I understand what you mean as to why that would be a problem.

Comment: What do you mean by $b^c$ when $b<0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$M_t=f(t,B_t)$ where $$f(t,x)=e^{-\left(x+\frac{t}{2}\right)\ln(x+t)}.$$

By Itô formula, $$dM_t=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x^2}\right)dt+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dB_t$$

Comment: Ah, I was making a mistake thinking that, because of the $t$, I had to use the multidimensional version. Thanks for your answer. Why do we have to use that representation of $f(t,x)$ though? Why not just set $f(t,x)=(x+t)^{-(x+\frac{1}{2}t)}$? Is it for ease of computing the derivatives?

Comment: Yes, to compute derivative (but you don't have o if you know directly the derivative of $f(x)^{g(x)}$